# cannot Importing WASP module - is there a replacement?

Tags: windows, powershell

I am trying to import WASP module (https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=wasp) but no luck.

is there a special instructions for installing it?

Moreover is there a replacement? as it is archived.

Comment: did you try [Chocolatey wasp](https://chocolatey.org/packages/wasp) install ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

easiest way is to use chocolatey, if you get stuck, follow the instructions here:
https://chocolatey.org/install

1) Install chocolatey from PowerShell:

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Scope Process -Force; iex ((New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadString('https://chocolatey.org/install.ps1'))
```

2) Install WASP form PowerShell as admin:

```
choco install wasp
```

3) Then run the following commands:

```
$WASP="C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\wasp"
$Reflection="C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\reflection"
$Autoload="C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\Autoload"
Copy-Item $WASP C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules -Recurse
Copy-Item $Reflection C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules -Recurse
Copy-Item $Autoload C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules -Recurse
Import-Module WASP
```

That's it, you should be golden after that, alternatively, you may download the .nupkg package and the .dll and placing them in the modules of powershell, you can use Nug PAckage explorer or change the .nupkg extension to .zip (lol).

Comment: this is working. yet I cannot find the Select-Window :-)

Comment: Yeah! Had a bunch of problems too, looks like a lot of the commandlets changed to something less-intuitive and the sample scripts don't work correctly, you may try an older version to get the old ones. I ended up using an Auto-It module for PowerShell:
https://www.autoitconsulting.com/site/scripting/autoit-cmdlets-for-windows-powershell/